# I was waking up or I was going to wake up or i would wake up

Tags: past-tense, future

I heard such sentence in a movie

"There was no chance I was waking up in the morning"

i understand the context and what the speaker wanted to say but
can I say it this way:

a) "There was no chance I was going to wake up in the morning"
b) "There was no chance I would wake up in the morning"

what are the differences to the original statement?

Comment: @David The OP hasn’t visited since December last year. No point railing against him.

Comment: @Lawrence — It passes the time.

Answer (score -1):

***"There was no chance I was waking up in the morning"*** - there is no way that you could possibly wake up in the morning - natural imagery of waking up.

***"There was no chance I was going to wake up in the morning"*** - there is no way that you could possibly make yourself wake up in the morning - human imagery of waking up.

***"There was no chance I would wake up in the morning"*** - there is no way that you could possibly wake up in the morning - natural imagery of waking up.